# Accessing a Capsule CRM API using Google App Script (convert from Curl Req)

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, get

I am trying to access a capsule CRM API (documentation [here](https://developer.capsulecrm.com/v2/operations/Party))

I am quite new to google app script and was trying to convert a curl request into a gas function using UrlFetchApp

I am trying to search for a certain party via the API -- they provide this endpoint:

GET

```
https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/parties/search
```

These are the Search parameters in the request:

- **q**    _________Type(String)___:The value to search for e.g. a name
- **page**______Type(Integer)__:The page of results to return
- **perPage**___Type(Integer)__:Number of entities to return per page

Their API Documentation says that you would read data from the API by doing the following:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" 
     -H "Accept: application/json" 
     https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/parties
```

The following is my gas function which does return the data, but does not effectively search for the correct record and return only the resultset. I would like to know if there is an easier and better way to perform this search?

```
function curlRequest(partyid) {

  var authenticationToken = "XvDEdg652DG...xYYRg";
  //var url = "https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/parties";
  var url = "https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/parties/search";
  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + authenticationToken,
  };

  var payload = {  
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "q":{
      "id":101756643
    },
     "page":1,
     "perPage": 50,
  };

  var options = {
    "headers" : headers,
    "method" : "GET"
  };

  Logger.log(options);
  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options));
  //var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

**EDIT:** based on feedback from Jack Brown:

It seems that the advice is correct, however the Capsule API is not geared for this structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `payload` is included in `options` then `fetch` will make a POST request *even if* you specify `method: 'get'`. This explains why you're receiving the *"Method not allowed"* error from the API - the "/api/v2/parties/search" endpoint accepts only GET requests and not POSTs.

So this means that for a GET request the search query should be included in the URL instead of in a payload. It's also probably best to control the escaping yourself instead of using the escaping provided by `UrlFetchApp` - this will allow for any special characters in the search term. GET is the default method so that can be omitted from the `options`.

Making those changes, the code becomes:

```
function myFunction() {
  var authenticationToken = "XvDEdg652DG...xYYRg";

  var query = "your search";
  var url = "https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/parties/search?q=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(query);

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + authenticationToken,
    "Accept": "application/json"
  };

  var options = {
    headers: headers,
    escaping: false
  };

  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options));    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never pass the payload to the urlFetch method, you create a payload. However you need to  insert the payload in the options object like so:

```
var options = {
    "headers" : headers,
    "method" : "GET",
    "payload" : payload
  };
```

Also -H in curl means a header value, so `"Accept": "application/json"` should be defined in the header

```
var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + authenticationToken,
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
```

Finally, your payload will look like this:

```
var payload = {  
    "q":{
      "id":101756643
    },
     "page":1,
     "perPage": 50,
  };
```

Now when you make the urlfetch Call it should work like excepted.

```
Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive assistance - you have helped me to understand the structures better

Comment: Can you modify the payload to this: `var payload = {  
    "q":101756643,
     "page":1,
     "perPage": 50,
  };` and try again?

Comment: Also seems like searching by tags is still [not documented](https://developer.capsulecrm.com/v2/operations/Party#searchParties). So cannot really tell the correct syntax or structure!